# Using isset inside form_input tag in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to show value in input box if value is present otherwise it must output empty textbox but this code is not working:

```
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname', if(isset($data1->Student_Name)) { echo $data1->Student_Name ; } ); ?><br />
```

Please help to solve my problem.

Comment: This code is a syntax error.

Comment: Can u please correct it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo form_input(array(
   'id' => 'dname', 
   'name' => 'dname', 
   'value' => isset($data1->Student_Name)? $data1->Student_Name : '' 
));
```